# unable to access Jquery Plugin color picker method in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery

I've downloaded a jquery Plugin [color picker Jquery Plugin](http://www.laktek.com/2008/10/27/really-simple-color-picker-in-jquery/)  and added it in static resources.

```
  <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.ColorPicker, 'ColorPicker/js/jquery.colorPicker.js')}"  />
```

I've referred it in my VF page in one of my inputtext field :

```
    jQuery = $.noConflict(true);
j$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#color1').colorPicker();
 });
 <apex:inputText id="color1" value="{!s1}" />
```

But the plugin method is not working.

Comment: Any errors on the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two problems:

1. You are using a variable j$ even though you haven't assigned a value to it.
2. You are using an ID-based match but Visualforce prefixes the id value that you set.

To solve these:

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function() {
    j$("[id$='color1']").colorPicker();
});
```

As Mohith suggests, you should also check your browser's console for problems like the jQuery JavaScript script or the color picker JavaScript script failing to load and any errors in your own JavaScript.

**PS**

For reference, see the jQuery [Attribute Ends With Selector [name$=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) documentation.

Alternatively you can use a CSS class (that typically has no styling) as a marker and match to that. A further benefit of that approach is that many elements in the page can have the same CSS class and jQuery naturally works with multiple elements, so it works well e.g. on table rows. Markup:

```
...
    j$(".colorPickerMarker").colorPicker();
...

<apex:inputText styleClass="colorPickerMarker" value="{!s1}" />
```

Comment: With the amount of user adoption towards jquery in VF pages it would a cool idea if salesforce comes out with a page attribute like <apex:page includejquery="true"> that takes care of all the jquery setting + loading jquery library for the page. Not that its too much work now but it would make it simpler.

Comment: @Rao I guess that would put Salesforce on the hook for things like version compatibility problems.

Comment: @KeithC can you please share some documentation link for accessing VF page component selector for jquery?

Comment: @user59759 Done in PS.